# Testing Pull Requests and Patches from Magento 2's GitHub

Tags: magento2, installation, composer, testing, git

I'd like to test the following patch applied by the community. As seen here, https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/13359/files.

Since I've always installed Magento via composer, is there an easy way to test this patch against a Magento 2.2.2 install where the code exists in the Vendor directory?  In Magento 1, I could see testing this in app/code/local/Mage, but since that no longer exists what does everyone recommend as a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, those two installation methods are largely incompatible. So your best option is probably to set up a second instance based on GitHub.

If you want to permanently add core bugfixes to a project without waiting for their release, you can create a module for the fix(es) and use a tool like https://github.com/staempfli/symlinker-pro to replace the files in `vendor` after `composer install`.